# How to make sure my "database" doesn't break if I add functionality in the future

Tags: java

In my app, I store data to a file using Serializable. The file contains a map of DictionaryEntry objects, a class I made myself. I noticed that when I added fields to that class, it broke my existing file in the sense that it would read it. The compiler threw an error ( I can't remember which one). The fields of DictionaryEntry contains some important fields that I absolutely cannot lose, so how would I go about adding more fields and methods to my DictionaryEntry class in the future without all my data being deleted?

EDIT: here is the error I got when I added a new field

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Logic.DictionaryEntry; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -637986868145725934, local class serialVersionUID = 1552091926235600295
```

Comment: How about using an actual database instead of a "database"? Or a serialisation format designed for backwards-compatibility, like protocol buffers?

Comment: @Andy Turner Its a personal app, nothing professional. Also I have absolutely no idea how actual databases work. Not to mention how to properly plug them into my app. I guess I could learn if that is the best option but that will take a lot of time.

Comment: I would recommend taking the time to learn; it will pay dividends in the (very near) future when your app (or the next app) outgrows your current approach. Structure your code in such a way that you can swap out one persistence layer for another, then you can keep using this approach and keep developing and learn about databases in parallel; then just swap your persistence layer once you are more confident.

Comment: @Andy Turner What do you mean by swapping persistence layers?

Comment: Your app should be largely agnostic to where its data is physically stored. You should simply have an interface that provides read and write methods. This allows you to change to a different way of storing it without disrupting the rest of your application.

Comment: @Andy Turner I see, well I think I've already done a good job of that. I am using MVC design, the save and load methods are in only one class. So if I were to change them, the rest of my application should still work the same.

Comment: You need to set a serialVersionUID by hand. Any number will do. You gurantee with this, that you make only compatible changes. And then of course you can only do compatilbe changes (like adding fields at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are asking is very generic and the issue that you are facing might be because of various different reason. I would request you to clarify this by providing the error that you are getting while compiling the code.

As far as adding mote fields and methods to your class is concerned, Serialization permits a certain amount of class variation, such that even after refactoring, **ObjectInputStream** will still read it just fine.
The critical things that the Java Object Serialization specification can manage automatically are:

- Adding new fields to a class .
- Changing the fields from static to    nonstatic.
- Changing the fields from transient to nontransient.

Going the other way (from nonstatic to static or nontransient to transient) or deleting fields requires additional massaging, depending on the degree of backward compatibility you require.

Comment: The problem here is that you are storing a map of objects, and while declaring a map you must have provided the value type as your class type. When you make changes to the class attributes, it invalidates the existing data because while DeSerializing the data it validates the objects in your file map with the class that you are trying to retrieve it to. Thus it finds it to be incompatible and thus this Error. This is one of the major drawback of storing data on a file using serializable.